# Jekyll: Manually whitelist directories and files to be copied to _site directory

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to specify a list of files or directories that one would like copied to the _site directory? I would like to copy those files as is, in the way the `webpack-copy-plugin` lets one use webpack to copy files from on place to another.

The files I want to copy are in `_includes`, in case this complicates things. I know I could make a top level directory in my project for these files I want copied to `_site`, but I want to keep things tidy and place everything in `_includes` (Jekyll already makes lots of files and folders in my project root, and I don't want any more).

I tried specifying the value for `include` in `_config.yml`, but this doesn't seem to be copying file to `_site`.

Any suggestions others can offer would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious, specifying in `_config.yml`:

```
include:
  - _includes
```

Copies over everything from `_includes`, while specifying:

```
include:
  - _includes/assets
```

does not copy over anything. I'll just use the former.